# Make div non-selectablee in ios

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a scrollable view that overlays an image. Such view consists of 2 divs, one is `scrollable`, basically a div with fixed height / width and overflow-y and thee other is `content`, an empty div with height greater than that of `scrollable`.

The issue I came across is that long pressing on them causes ios to select a div. I tried setting `user-select` on both of them, but it didn't do the trick. I'm not sure which one of them is being selected, but I believe it is `content`.

It is important to note that both of these are created programmatically via

```
const mytDiv = document.createElement('div')
```

and appended to the body. Styles for them are set via

```
myDiv.style.cssText = "user-select: none;"
```

Here is basic html generated

```
<div class="scrollable" style="...">
  <div class="content" style="..."></div>
</div>
```

And this is ios selection I am seeing after long-press even with `user-select` set to "none".

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on ios, and safari browsers i believe it was like this.

```
-webkit-touch-callout : none
-webkit-user-select:none
//webkit-touch-callout : none: No callout option will be shown when the user's touch and holds on the element with this attribute.
//webkit-user-select : none: You cannot select text on Safari on macOS, if you do a right-click no options to copy is displayed.
```

if you want all other browsers too:

```
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
-o-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be doing the trick, divs are still selectable. I wonder if it has something to do with them being created by js

Comment: Can u give me a live snippet if u can !

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
myDiv.style += `
-webkit-touch-callout:none;
-webkit-user-select:none;
-khtml-user-select:none;
-moz-user-select:none;
-ms-user-select:none;
user-select:none;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
`;
```